# Problem with the formatting of a redis response

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, redis

I am trying to reformat an incoming string from redis to the client that looks like this...

```
"[{'user_id': 1, 'username': 'one', 'coins_won': 10}, {'user_id': 2, 'username': 'two', 'coins_won': 20}]"
```

The desired result would be an actual array with objects inside like

```
[{user_id: 1, 'username': 'one', coins_won: 10}]
```

I've tried multiple methods to no avail, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to deserialize the incoming string in your client program. Something like (assuming you're using jQuery):

```
var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
```